# Are harmonic mappings non-singular outside a set of measure zero?

Tags: ap.analysis-of-pdes, riemannian-geometry, geometric-measure-theory, laplacian, harmonic-functions

Let $g$ be a smooth Riemannian metric on the closed $n$-dimensional unit disk $\mathbb D^n$.

Let $f: \mathbb D^n \to \mathbb{R}^n$ be a smooth orientation-preserving **immersion**, and let $\omega :\mathbb D^n \to \mathbb{R}^n$ be the harmonic map corresponding to the Dirichlet problem imposed by $f$, i.e. $\omega|_{\partial \mathbb D^n}=f|_{\partial \mathbb D^n}$.

> Must $d\omega$ be invertible outside a set of measure zero in $\mathbb D^n$?

**Here is a complete solution for the case where $g$ is real-analytic:**

First, we note that $d\omega$ is singular on as set of positive measure if and only if it is singular everywhere on $\mathbb D^n$: Since $\omega$ must be real-analytic, so is $\det d\omega$, and the zero-set of a real-analytic function which is not identically zero has measure zero.

However $d\omega$ cannot be singular everywhere, since

$$ \int_{\mathbb D^n} \det d\omega = \int_{\mathbb D^n} \det df>0,$$

which finishes the job.

I am not sure how to deal with the case where $g$ is smooth but not real-analytic:

One idea I had is to approximate the smooth $g$ with analytic metrics $g(t)$, and to look at the corresponding harmonic maps  $\omega(t)$: If $g(t)$ converges to $g$ in a sufficiently strong sense, then the $\omega(t)$ should converge to the harmonic map $\omega$ associated with the original metric $g$. However, I am not sure that this gets us anywhere, since the limiting map may have many more singular points compared to the $\omega(t)$. (The rank can fall in the limit).

*Other observations:*

We know that near $\partial \mathbb{D}^n$ $\text{rank}(d\omega) \ge n-1$ because  $f$ is an immersion.  Perhaps there is hope that *somewhere* near the boundary, $d\omega$ will be invertible.

What happens if we assume that $\text{rank}(d\omega) = n-1$ on a neighbourhood of $\partial \mathbb D^n$? Does this lead to a contradiction?

> The following example shows that, at least on all $\partial \mathbb D^n$, the rank can be exactly $n-1$, if we only consider the "local problem": Set

$$\omega(r,\theta)=((r+r^{-1})\cos \theta,(r+r^{-1})\sin \theta)).$$ $\omega$ is harmonic on $\mathbb D^2 \setminus \{(0,0)\}$ and agrees with the immersion $(2x_1,2x_2)$ on $\partial \mathbb D^2$, but its rank on  $\partial \mathbb D^2$ is $1$ everywhere.

$\omega$ is not really a counter-example to the question even on $\mathbb D^2 \setminus \{(0,0)\}$, since $d\omega$ is invertible in the interior.

Comment: Have you looked at the paper of Schoen and Uhlenbeck? I believe it answers your question in the affirmative.

Comment: If you mean this paper: https://projecteuclid.org/euclid.jdg/1214436923, as far as I can see, it only considers aspects of continuity and smoothness. (It does not address the issue of invertibility of the differential).

Comment: I think it might be worth digging through it. My guess is that along they way, some of what they do can be used to study your question.

Comment: @AsafShachar Yes I realized it only showed that $d\omega$ couldn't vanish on a set of positive measure.

Comment: @AsafShachar As you point out in your edit, you are missing a step in the analytic case.  The map $\omega(r,\theta)=((r+r^{-1})\cos\theta, (r+r^{-1} \sin \theta)$ is harmonic on $\mathbb{D}^2\backslash \{(0,0\}$ and agrees with the  (harmonic) immersion $(2x_1,2 x_2)$ on $\partial \mathbb{D}^2$ but is not an immersion on $\partial \mathbb{D}^2$.  This means you are going to have to use that $\omega$ is harmonic on the whole disk.

Comment: I believe you use the area formula to prove that $\det d\omega$ is non-zero on a set of positive measure and hence conclude what you want in the real analytic case (I think the smooth case is also true, but don't know how to close the argument).  The idea is that since $f(\partial \mathbb{D})=\omega(f\partial \mathbb{D})$ is an immersed $n-1$ dimensional submanifold, the (GMT) solution of the Plateau problem is non-trivial and so $\omega(\mathbb{D})$ has non-zero volume.  This means $\det (d\omega^\top d\omega)>0$ on a set of positive measure.

Comment: @RBega2 Thank you, this seems like a nice and beautiful argument! After speaking with a colleague, I now have a more elementary argument for why $\det d\omega \neq 0$ on a set of positive measure: We must have $   \int_{\mathbb D^n} \det d\omega = \int_{\mathbb D^n} \det df>0$, since $f$ and $\omega$ agree on the boundary. This settles the analytic case.